# How to find updated data

Tags: c#, sql-server, logging, connector

I want to export live data from my system to a message broker like service bus to use for searching, logging, etc. To do so, I need to find out when a row is created in the DB or if it is updated or deleted. How can I do that?

Is there any better way? 
I really don't like to implement it in my application service layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of up and down, I think the best way is to use a column in all tables like modify date. ModifyDate can be updated either when the code is changing/adding the row, or by having a trigger on the table.

Then in the code each time save the last date that we check the db and query based on modify date.

Answer (score 1):

Create Trigger for insert, update and delete

Example :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[tablename] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    --Your process
GO
```

Comment: a trigger on each table? but that is even worse :(